# Как заполнить map?

Tags: java, map

Задача следующая: мне надо написать метод, который на вход принимает какой либо текст и возвращает `Map`, которая хранит количество повторений каждого буквенного символа в этом тексте. Я разбил строку на массив символов, сохранил в `ArrayList`, отсортировал его, затем посчитал сколько раз повторяется каждый символ и теперь надо это занести в `Map`. Вот то, что я пока сделал:

```
public static Map<Character, Integer> countSymbolsNew(String text)throws Exception{
        //сделать отсортированный список
        //посчитать количество повторений каждого символа и занести в переменную
        //результат добавить в мапу
        if (text == null)
            throw new Exception("No text");

    Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    ArrayList<Character> chars = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
        char c = text.toLowerCase().charAt(i);
        if (Character.isLetter(c)){
            chars.add(c);
        }
    }
    Collections.sort(chars);
    System.out.println(chars);
    //надо взять первый элемент массива, пройти им по всему списку и если повторяется то плюсовать счетчик
    //если не повторился то счетчик равен 1
    int maxCount = 0;
    for (Character aChar : chars) {
        int count = 0;
        for (Character ch : chars) {
            if (aChar.equals(ch)){
                count++;
            }
        }
        if (count > maxCount){
            maxCount = count;
        }
        System.out.print(count + " ,");

    }


    return map;
}
```

Теоретически я вроде представляю как добавляются элементы в Map, а на практике вот что-то не могу дальше ничего сделать. Прошу помощи и объяснений.

Comment: `map.put(aChar, count)` пробовали? Но на самом деле код сильно переусложнен. Там одно цикла хватит.

Comment: Мой наставник, по видимому, специально не даёт мне идти лёгкими путями )) Надо именно в такой последовательности, как у меня сделано, делать. Теперь мне надо пройти по массиву моих символов и в условии указать, что заносить в ключ, а что в значение. Вот с этим у меня и проблема

Comment: Я вообще не пойму как тут может быть подсчитано количество каждого символа в строке. Как ты определил какой символ где?

Comment: @YuriiS возможно, наставник предлагал классический вариант uniq, поэтому и предложил вначале отсортировать. Вот только в этом случае во внутреннем цикле не нужно снова бежать по всем символам, он на самом деле не нужен.

Comment: KoVadim, а как быть ? я уже третьи сутки в полнейшем ступоре (((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если "ментор" предложил сортировать массив и явно боится сделать лишний раз put (ну мало какой там бзык в голове у человека), то можно сделать и так. В принципе просто добавление `map.put(aChar, count)` уже решает задачу, и даже @Roman Danilov это и написал. Но у этого решение есть один минус - квадратичная сложность. И если бы массив не был отсортирован, то можно было бы наверно и закрыть глаза на это. Но массив уже отсортирован, поэтому, одинаковые элементы идут подряд. Нужно только бежать и суммировать. Где то так

```
public static Map<Character, Integer> countSymbolsNew(String text)throws Exception{
        //сделать отсортированный список
        //посчитать количество повторений каждого символа и занести в переменную
        //результат добавить в мапу
        if (text == null)
            throw new Exception("No text");

    Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    ArrayList<Character> chars = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
        char c = text.toLowerCase().charAt(i);
        if (Character.isLetter(c)){
            chars.add(c);
        }
    }
    Collections.sort(chars);
    System.out.println(chars);

    Character c = chars.get(0);
    int count = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < chars.size(); i++) {
        // проверим текущий символ. я не знаю, можно ли тут просто равно
        if (chars.get(i).equals(c)) {
            // символ тот же - просто счетчик увеличим
            count++;
        } else {
           // другой символ, добавим предыдущий и запомним новый
            map.put(c, count);
            c = chars.get(i);
            count = 1;
        }
    }
    // а это уже хвост, который также нужно обработать.
    map.put(c, count);

    return map;
}
```

Comment: KoVadim, похоже это именно то, что надо. Спасибо, буду разбираться.

Comment: KoVadim, код работает и без этой строки - // а это уже хвост, который также нужно обработать.
    map.put(c, count);  зачем обрабатывать хвост ?

Comment: код то работает, но неправильно. Хвост - это последняя последовательность символов. Так как не произойдет смены символа, то и код в else ветке не отработает.

Comment: KoVadim, странно... я сейчас тэстил и всё отрабатывает, как надо...

Comment: попробуйте на строке вида "aaaaaaa"

Comment: KoVadim, понял, такой вариант строки я не учитывал. Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Если по простому и без возможностей Java8, то достаточно этого:

```
public static Map<Character, Integer> countSymbolsNew(String text)throws Exception {
    if (text == null)
        throw new Exception("No text");

    Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
        char c = text.toLowerCase().charAt(i);
        if (Character.isLetter(c)) {
            if (map.containsKey(c)) {
                map.put(c, map.get(c) + 1);
            } else {
                map.put(c, 1);
            }
        }
    }
    return map;
}
```

Здесь мы просто перебираем массив символов и кладем каждый символ в мапу. А если такой символ уже есть, просто кладем в мапу тот же символ, но с увеличенным счетчиком, старый при этом затирается.

Если принципиально делать так, как делаете вы, то можно сделать следующим образом:

```
//надо взять первый элемент массива, пройти им по всему списку и если повторяется то плюсовать счетчик
//если не повторился то счетчик равен 1
for (Character aChar : chars) {
    if (!map.containsKey(aChar)) {
        int count = 0;
        for (Character ch : chars) {
            if (aChar.equals(ch)){
                count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.print(count + " ,");
        map.put(aChar, count);
    }
}
```

Comment: У меня есть такое решение, но оно не проходит. Вот что мне ответил преподаватель: но нужно точно поправить
“так же есть моменты неэфективно код написать, цикл , там много лишнего и каждый раз пут в мапу тоже лучше не делать, эьто можно сделать один раз”

через иф такие условия писать тоже не сильно хорошо потому что запутывает, как я запутался
если переписать это чтобы put происходил один раз код тоже будет понятнее.

Comment: @YuriiS, обновил ответ. И maxCount вам так же не нужна

Comment: Roman Danilov, фактически мне надо добавить в своём коде строчку map.put(aChar, count); и Map заполняется. Странно что я не додумался до этого очевидного шага. Спасибо. Надеюсь у меня примут этот вариант.

Comment: @YuriiS, не только map.put, но и условие contains, чтобы не бежать по тем символам, которые уже посчитаны

Comment: Roman Danilov , почему то считает и без условия contains. А почему ? Или в этом случае уйдёт больше времени на работу программы ?

Comment: @YuriiS, считает, да. Но если буквы в строке повторяются, то он их так же посчитает, просто несколько раз одну и ту же букву пересчитает)

Answer (score 0):

```
public Map <Character, Integer> letterCalculate (String text){
    Map <Character, Integer> mapCounter = new TreeMap <>();
    for (char ch : text.toCharArray()) {
        if (Character.isLetter(ch)) mapCounter.put(ch, mapCounter.get(ch) == null ? 1 : mapCounter.get(ch) + 1);
    }
    return mapCounter;
}
```